# Erro ao retornar formulário dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, html

Pretendo criar um formulário dinâmico mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> javprogram.js:377 Uncaught TypeError: "#retorno3".html is not a
> function
> at Object.success (javprogram.js:377)
> at fire (jquery-latest.js:3119)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.js:3231)
> at done (jquery-latest.js:9275)
> at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-latest.js:9685)

Código para criar o formulário:
HTML:

```
<form action="#!" id="retper">     
                      
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_perfil', function(){  
   var perf = $(this).attr("id_perfil");

   $.ajax({  
        url:"perfil.php",  
        method:"POST",
        cache: false,               
        data:{perf:perf},               
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){
            var linha = ``;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

                Nome = data[i][0];
                Email = data[i][1];
                Acesso = data[i][2];
                Foto = data[i][3];
               
                linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${Nome}">
                        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label for="Utilizador">Nome</label>        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${Email}">
                        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label for="Email1">Email</label>        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="${Acesso}">
                        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label for="Acesso">Acesso</label>        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label class="filelabel">
                         <i class="fa fa-paperclip">
                         </i>
                         <span class="title">
                            Add Foto
                         </span>
                         <img src="./images/${Foto}" alt="">
                      </label>
                      </div>`;
                }
                    
                ("#retper").html(linha);
        }

    });
});
```

php:

```
$perf = $_POST["perf"];    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT dados.Utilizadores.Nome, Email, dados.Niveis_Acessos .Nome AS Acesso, Foto    
FROM dados.Utilizadores LEFT OUTER JOIN dados.Niveis_Acessos     
ON dados.Niveis_Acessos.Id = dados.Utilizadores.Niveis_acesso_id WHERE dados.Utilizadores.Id = :perf");    
$stmt->bindValue(':perf', $perf, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();    
$json = [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);    
    $json[]= [(string)$Nome, (string)$Email, (string)$Acesso, (string)$Foto];
}    
echo json_encode($json);
```

Já verifiquei e o script php retorna corretamente os dados. O problema está ao construir o `HTML`.

Comment: $("#retper").html(linha); Faltou o $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//apenas um exemplo
let linha='<input type="text" value="vou para o formulario">';
//correto.
//vai  definir o conteúdo do form com id = Outroretper.
$("#Outroretper").html(linha);

//vai dar o erro, está faltando o $
("#retper").html(linha);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#!" id="Outroretper">     
                      
</form>


<form action="#!" id="retper">     
                      
</form>
```